# Get label name on JSON Python

Tags: python, json

i am a newbie on JSON,
I want to get just 'label' from my JSON data
here is my JSON data, i am using json.dumps to turn it into JSON format

```
a = json.dumps({"Name": "Robert",
   "Date" : "January 17th, 2017",
   "Address" : "Jakarta"})
```

I want to print just the label of my JSON data, is there any possible way to do it?
The result that i want is

```
Name
Date
Address
```

Comment: Once this is JSON, this becomes difficult. Why don't you just use the Python data structure? JSON here makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must convert `json` to `dict` and then the `labels` are the same as the `keys`.

```
import json
a = json.dumps({"Name": "Robert",
   "Date" : "January 17th, 2017",
   "Address" : "Jakarta"})
for key in json.loads(a):
    print(key)
```

output:

```
Name
Date
Address
```

**Optional**:

If you want to access the values ​​of each item

```
import json
a = json.dumps({"Name": "Robert",
   "Date" : "January 17th, 2017",
   "Address" : "Jakarta"})
d = json.loads(a)
for key in d:
     print("key: {}, value: {}".format(key, d[key]))
```

**Python2**

```
for key, value in json.loads(a).iteritems():
     print("key: {}, value: {}".format(key, value))
```

**Python3**

```
for key, value in json.loads(a).items():
     print("key: {}, value: {}".format(key, value))
```

Output:

```
key: Name, value: Robert
key: Date, value: January 17th, 2017
key: Address, value: Jakarta
```

Comment: haha you posted the answer, literally while i was typing it. :D

Comment: :P  The solution is very simple :V

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and i got the result Date, Name and then Address at last, why it can happen? It should be like what you said

Comment: @M.AgusTriMulyono 
If my answer helps you mark it correctly.

Comment: @eyllanesc the result what i got is Date, Name, then Address, why it can be happen, it should be Name, Date, then Address

Comment: @M.AgusTriMulyono  Dictionaries order the keys for quick access.

Comment: @eyllanesc so why doesnt it print Address, Date, then Name? and how to get the result ordered like before?

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions made:

1. I assumed that you are using python3.x

You can do it as follows:

```
import json
a = json.dumps({"Name": "Robert", "Date" : "January 17th, 2017", "Address" : "Jakarta"})
a_dict = json.loads(a)
for key in a_dict.keys():
    print (key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use loads to create a json object. So in Python3:

```
import json

a = json.loads('{"Name":"Robert","Date":"January 17th, 2017","Address":"Jakarta"}')

for key, value in a.items() :
    print (key)
```

Comment: `loads` **does not** create a JSON "object". It *deserializes* a string in JSON format into a *python object*

Comment: I meant set of dicts from string

Comment: the result is Date, Name and Address, why it can be happen?

Answer (score 0):

Below python code will get the json file as input and produce a file with labels from json at all levels.

```
from re import sub
from os.path import abspath, realpath, join, dirname
import json
Srcfilename = input("Enter Srcfilename: ") 
file = abspath(Srcfilename)
file_open = open(file, 'r')
file_read = file_open.read()
#print(file_read)
jdata = json.loads(file_read)

def get_keys(dl, keys_list1):
        if isinstance(dl, dict):
            for key1,info1 in dl.items():
               # print(key1)
                keys_list1.append(key1)
                #print("\nlistinfo:",info1)
                if isinstance(info1, dict) or isinstance(info1, list)  :
                        get_keys(info1, keys_list1)
        elif isinstance(dl, list):
             if isinstance(dl[0], dict):
                for key2,info2 in dl[0].items():
                  #  print(key2)
                    keys_list1.append(key2)
                   # print("\nlistinfo:",info2)
                    if isinstance(info2, dict) or isinstance(info2, list)  :
                        get_keys(info2, keys_list1)
        keys_list1 = list(dict.fromkeys(keys_list1))                
        keylist='\n'.join(map(str, keys_list1))
        
        return keylist              
      

        
keys_list1=[]
Tgtfilename = input("Enter Tgtfilename: ") 
new_file = abspath(Tgtfilename)
new_file_open = open(new_file, 'w')
content=get_keys(jdata, keys_list1)
print (keys_list1)
new_file_open.write(content)
new_file_open.close()
```